# Use a laptop as a desktop with multiple monitors without using the original laptop screen

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors

My dad asked me if this was possible and I'm really uncertain. It seems like it would be easy enough to change the power settings for the laptop and clone the display to an additional monitor but that allows for only one screen.

He commutes a lot for work, and his ideal situation is that when he is in the office he can close his laptop and put it on a dock, essentially turning it into a desktop with an external keyboard, mouse, and monitor.

Conceptually this seems easy enough for just one additional monitor but he would like to use two. Is there some way to make this happen? I was thinking maybe just leave the laptop as an active screen and add two monitors, so essentially he would have three monitors but only use two. I foresee this causing issue though, as Windows might want to open programs on that screen, which would be frustrating and confusing for him.

Any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into the hardware option of [Docking Stations](https://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-ThinkPad-Adapter-40A20090US-Packaged/dp/B00E0E2DIE)?  Without knowing what laptop he has, I cannot provide you with an option that would work.  Although, look around for a docking station that is compatible, it will do what you are asking.

Comment: Works fine with my macbook pro : can use both screens or just the external if I wish.

Comment: If you're using a multi-port docking station with the lid closed, this is the default behavior...

Comment: ah okay I assumed that it would be impossible to ignore the initial laptop screen. I did look into docking stations but that just seemed like it was for peripherals and not a full conversion (i.e. you would be forced to use the initial screen) I will dig a bit deeper into that, thanks!